# The physics behind The Great Flood

Tags: gravity, mass, water, volume

The book of Genesis floats (pardon the pun) some interesting numbers when discussing the Great Flood.  For example, it rained for 40 days and 40 nights, and at the end of that time, the entire planet was covered in water.

I think we can deduce how much water that would have had to be, estimating that the highest peaks in the Himalayas were covered with water. (8,848 meters above sea level)

My questions are, how fast would the rain have had to come to raise the ocean level that high in 40 days and nights, how much would the mass of the earth have changed for this event, and would that significantly alter the strength of gravity on earth?

Comment: @CrazyBuddy There are other ways of adding water to earth, which are happening continually btw: http://csep10.phys.utk.edu/astr161/lect/comets/smallcomets.html. There are theories that the water on earth comes from comets too so it is not overly imaginative.

Comment: @CrazyBuddy The imagination comes from the Bible. The Himalayas come in because supposedly the arc of Noah stopped on mountain Ararat. If one wants to find the level of myth there to the level of physics it is not a bad question. The earth could have fallen in a bunch of water commets for forty days, for example and certain regions flooded all through, though the Himalayas are excessive.

Comment: Well the bible states the earth was completely covered in water.  If that is the case, then the highest point above sea level would need to be covered.  That's about 5 miles of water, and I cannot help but think that sort of thing would be significant for mass, gravity, and the spin of the earth..

Comment: From the FAQ, under questions that should not be asked here: "Questions about fictional physics."

Comment: Several people flagged this, so I'm closing it, but I suppose at its core it is just a question about how much the Earth's mass/gravity would be affected by the addition of a surface layer of water 5 miles thick, and that doesn't necessarily have to be off topic. Jeremy, perhaps if you could explain what you've tried to figure that out and why it's not working, it could be a much better question.

Comment: The text in Noah's flood _in Hebrew_ does _not_ say that the himalayas were covered, it says that the water went within 15 cubits of the top of the sky-dome. THe sky-dome (Heb:rakia') is beaten flat out of malleable substance by God in day 2, it covers the flat Earth-plate. The Genesis flat Earth extended roughly from India to Greece/Sudan, and went up a few hundred meters (Jacob's ladder). The flood water comes from the water on top of the sky-dome (which falls rain) and from the abyss below, on which the whole Earth is floating, (groundwater). The two waters filled the bubble we live in.

Comment: Given they were using Babylonian cosmology, the water is about 500 meters high, covering a land area less than Asia, so roughly the Atlantic ocean. It's not too big. Any attempt to match the Genesis flat-Earth cosmology to Greek round Earth cosmology is anachronistic sillyness religious people do to believe the nonsense in the Bible has any basis in historical events. The flood myth is one of the stories in Genesis which originate in Hinduism (Vishnu's fish flood), along with the Abraham/Sarah stories (Brahma/Saraiswati), and the Jewish meditative tradition. Judaism is an offshoot of Hinduism.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky, it was an odd thought that struck me, as it seemed a lot of water, but I didn't know if it would be statistically significant to things like gravity, and if the time frame for getting that level of water delivered to the surface was realistic.  Dunno why people can't just stick to the numbers.  I wasn't looking for a history lesson, and I certainly don't see how this qualifies as "fictional" physics.

Comment: @Jeremy people get a little touchy about anything that mentions a religious or fictional story, but like I said, this is not a religious question at heart. The real issue with it IMO is that it's kind of trivial - no offense, but the calculations you would need to answer your questions are explained in every intro-level physics textbook and many websites. For a question like that, we'd like to see that you made at least _some_ effort to figure it out yourself. If you have no physics education, that's okay, but you could mention that and say that you searched Wikipedia or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical tropical storm drops about 40inches/rain in 24hours (sorry for the medieval units!)

So 40days/nights = 1600inches, or 40metres of water. If you want to cover even reasonable mountains you have to rain a lot harder than that = 200x harder.

Comment: Well that's one of the questions, and it doesn't look like I'll be getting any others.  I don't understand why this sparked such a controversy, I was just trying to recreate conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The closest to a physical discussion of the Great Flood may be
http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/faq-noahs-ark.html#flood